# Running django project without django installation

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have developed a project with **Django framework(python and mysql DB)** in Linux OS(Ubuntu 12.04), I want to run this project in localhost in **another machine** with Linux(Ubuntu 12.04) without installing Django here, is it possible **run a django project without django installation.** Is there any way to run so?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You sure have to add it to your Python libraries in order for Python to be able to `import django`. Don't know how to do that without actually installing Django though.

Comment: @dm03514 Aptitude package will just automatically install Django into system Python. All it does is essentially automates the install process.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order to be able to use regular Django, it has to be installed since you have to be able to do `import django`. However it is never a good idea to install Django as a system-level Python package. It is always best to work with virtualenvs. They allows you to work on multiple projects where each project might require different packages to be installed, and different projects might require to use different version of the same package. In addition to being used  development, virtualenvs are very useful to install packages on remote machines even if you do not have root privileged.

All you have to do is download [virtualenv.py](https://raw.github.com/pypa/virtualenv/master/virtualenv.py) and then do the following on the remote machine:

```
$ wget https://raw.github.com/pypa/virtualenv/master/virtualenv.py
$ python virtualenv.py venv
$ cd venv
$ source bin/activate
$ pip install django
```

That will create a virtualenv, into which you can install any Python packages without a need for root privileges. More about virtualenv [here](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/).

Answer (score 3):

You can try [DjangoOnAStick](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DjangoOnAStick) or [portablepython](http://www.portablepython.com/). Both don't require an installation to work. You can also try [PyRun](http://www.egenix.com/products/python/PyRun/) it's a One file Python Runtime that also doesn't need installation you can watch a [video about it](http://pyvideo.org/video/1300/pyrun-the-one-file-python-runtime-environment) by the creator.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows:

We can write the below 4 statements to use django & check if it is installed.

`import sys
sys.path.insert(0,r'C:\Python34\django-master')
import django
print (django.get_version())`

C:\Python34\django-master is the path where the django setup downloaded from https://github.com/django/django is kept on the Windows 7 machine.